# How to vectorize a for loop of yields?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, yield

I currently have the following for loop that loops over each row and yields a `RowClass` object that's instantiated based on a row in `df`

```
# df is a Pandas dataframe
for i in range(len(df)):
  # RowClass is a C++ class that's exposed through pybind that simply converts the row to an
  # object with attributes corresponding to each column
  yield RowClass(df.iloc[i])
```

Is it possible to vectorize this and optimize away the for loop?

Comment: it really isn't clear to me what you are asking for. Vectorize *what*? What is the *result* you are looking for

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga My understanding is for loops in Python are really slow, and it's best to not use for loops if you can vectorize an operation. In this case I am looping over each row and yielding a RowClass object. I'm basically asking if it's possible to do the same in a faster way without for loops?

Comment: Vectorization is a concept that applies to operations on numpy/pandas data structures. But in this case, you are obviously writing a generator. Again, it isn't clear **what the result is that you are actually expecting**. Vectorize *what*?

Comment: In this case, you could probably just use `df.apply(RowClass, axis=1)`. Of course, now you are not really going to benefit from vectorization anyway since this is 1) using `.apply` 2) results in a pandas data structure with `dtype=object` (because you are instantiating a Python class). But it really isn't clear what your *result* is supposed to be, the above gives you a `pd.DataFrame` or `pd.Series`, but you have a generator above. I don't know if that works for you or not because you *haven't really explained anything*.

Comment: Don't be afraid of for loops: "explicit is better than implicit"  and premature optimization is (almost) always a bad idea.  If you're trying to make your code faster you should look into panda's documentation and/or the `profile` (or `cProfile`) module.

Comment: So, you are wrapping your pandas data frame rows in a class. You are essentially forfeiting vectorization after that point. So again, without understanding what you are actually doing it's hard to really say anything.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ah, so I specifically need the result to be generators in this case

Comment: Then "vectorization" really doesn't make any sense. Why is that a requirement, though? Why not just an iterable?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So I don't have much experience with Python, but I'm under the assumption that "for loops are slow" and that one should try to avoid for loops over some vectorized operation. I just wasn't sure is there was a vectorized way to generate these generators instead of having to loop over each row